# Why c++ constrained algorithms are in the ranges namespace?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Ranges in C++20 are not very appetizing for many people who came from less-verbose languages like Python, because typing `std::ranges::` is too verbose.

The proposals seem to have own rationales, but what I don't understand are constrained algorithms, consider `std::sort` and `std::ranges::sort`:

`std::sort`: [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

`std::ranges::sort`: [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort)

I don't really understand why we have to type like this

```
std::vector<int> v {3, 1, 4, 2, 6};
std::ranges::sort(v);
```

Oh, my... just why? Why we can't have `std::sort(v);`? I can't find any overload resolution ambiguity between the range version of `std::ranges::sort()` and all versions of `std::sort()`. (I understand a version that takes an iterator pair, I hate the range version)

Do you know the reason behind this decision?

Comment: Although you can't re-use the name `std`, if you want a shorter name for `std::ranges::sort`, you have a couple of choices. `using namespace std::ranges; /* ... */ sort (v);` or `using s = std::ranges; /* ... */ s::sort(v);` As for "why?" Mostly just that `std` is already bloated, holding a gazillion possible names, so something like `using namespace std;` is dangerous, but `using namespace std:::ranges;` should be quite safe.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I completely agree with you, but `using namespace whatever;` is often frowned upon (of course, in non-header files) to many engineers including some of my coworkers

Comment: There's good reason for that, at least with the `std` namespace. But `std::ranges` is a whole different story--the clear intent is that you generally bring it into scope, so you can do it's `foo | sort | take(6) | ...` kind of stuff.